Weak continuity
I have the following Hilbert spaces: $L^2, H^1$, and the following definitions:

$u \in C_w(0,T;H^1)$ if $\forall t_0 \in [0,T]$ i have $\lim_{t \to t_0} (u(t)-u(t_0),v)_{H^1} \forall v \in H^1$ is the definition of a weakly continuous function in $H^1$

$u \in C(0,T;L^2)$ if $u(t) \to u(t_0)$ in $L^2$ for $t \to t_0$


My problem is: if $u(t)$ weakly converges to some $w$ in $H^1$ and the same $u(t) \in C(0,T;L^2)$, then i have that $u(t) \in C_w(0,T;H^1)$, but I do not know how to prove it.
Can someone give me a hint or prove it?

Can you please clarify your question? It makes little sense now. What is converging in which space? This should boil down to uniqueness of weak limits.

$u(t) \in L^\infty (0,T,H^1)$, thus it is bounded in $H^1$, thus it admits a subsequence which weakly converges to some element in $H^1$. Honestly I do not know why I need this, but my professor told us that by having these two conditions we can prove the latter.

There is no sequence? If $u(t_n) \rightharpoonup u_1$ in $V$ and $u(t_n) \to u_2 $ in $H$ for some $t_n \to t_0$ then $u_1=u_2$. Is that your question?

sorry, i meant that it is bounded in time, so as $t \to t_0$, $u(t) \to u(t_0)$ weakly in $H^1$. Maybe I do not have clear the definition of weak continuity, because now that you made me notice, from the weak convergence i should have weak continuity in that space, but my professor specified that we also need continuity in $L^2$
